# Best approach to go: one table for each operation or one table for all operations?

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design

I'm designing the database for a solution. I'm facing the following scenario:

- The user can add a product. This product will belong to a specific operation: "SELL", "BUY", etc.
- Another user can mark the product as interested. So, I'll have a table to generate the users which are interested in something.

I'm struggling to decide which approach to go:

1. I can create one table for each operation, something like "ProductSell", "ProductBuy", etc. The same for interested users ("InterestedProductSell", "InterestedProductBuy", etc).

```

```
User               ProductSell   ProductBuy   InterestBuy                 InterestSell
____________       ___________   __________   ___________                 ____________
Id                 Id            Id           ProductId (ProductBuy PK)   ProductId (ProductSell PK)
Name               Title         Title        UserId                      UserId
Username           UserId        UserId       Date                        Date
```

```

2. I can create one table for all operations, with a column named "Operation". Same for interested users.

```

```
User            Operation              Product       Interest
____________    _________              ___________   __________
Id              Id                     Id            ProductId (ProductBuy or ProductSell PK)        
Name            Name (Buy, sell, etc)  Title         UserId                     
Username                               UserId        Date      
                                       Operation
```

```

Can you give me your opinions about these two approach, or even a third approach that I didn't realize? Things like performance, optimization, maintenance, coding... I need another options other than my sight about this.

If it's matter, I'm working with SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

your 2nd approach of having a separate column for `Operation` looks good

**user** Table

```
uid
name
```

**product** Table

```
pid
name
```

**userproduct** Table

```
uid
pid
operation
time
```

Comment: RADAR, thanks for the tip. The approach is slight different than your sight. Please check my answer above to see my domain and understand what I want to do.